# HAProxy hostname identify and route

Tags: proxy, redis, routes, haproxy

Well, I have a doubt hope someone can help me with that, let me explain some details about what I want to have done.

I have two redis host in the backend: one is the current master (hostname redis-master) and the other one is a slave (redis-slave) and finally a HAProxy configured to route the request to the master directly using the port 6378.

What I need is identify the incoming hostname and route to the correct server/backend, like: 
**redis -h redis-master -p 6378** and get connection to the master server and 
**redis -h redis-slave -p 6378** and yes, get connected to the slave.

I don't want use domain names, just the hostname that I have already configured.
I did a configuration but does not work for me. Someone can take a look and help me? I apreciatte it a lot.

Thanks in advance, below is my configuration.

```
    frontend redis-clusterA
        bind *:6378

        acl masterA hdr(host) -i redis-master
        acl slaveA hdr(host) -i redis-slave

        use_backend redis-clusterA if masterA
        use_backend redis-slaveA if slaveA

    backend redis-clusterA
            mode tcp
            balance first
            option tcp-check

            tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
            tcp-check expect string role:master
        server redis-clusterA:redis-master:6378 redis-master:6378 maxconn 1024 check inter 1s

    backend redis-slaveA
            mode tcp
            balance first
            option tcp-check

            tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
            tcp-check expect string role:slave
        server redis-clusterA:redis-slave:6378 redis-slave:6378 maxconn 1024 check inter 1s
```

When I connect trought HAProxy i receive this response: Error: Server closed the connection

Someone can help me with that? 
Regards and thanks !